# Create a function to enter a to z in a dynamic array using redim preserve

Tags: vb.net

I am learning VB scripting and i am very much new to this concept...

Please tell how to writ the below program

Create a function to enter a to z in a dynamic array using redim preserve.

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: Please show your own effort.

Comment: Is this actually .Net?...or is it VBScript (.vbs)?

Comment: Why such a weird requirement? What does dynamic array even mean? You can just do: Dim letters() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()

Answer (score 0):

I happened to already have a snippet to do what you were looking for, so here it is:

```
Const StartChar = "a"c
Const EndChar = "z"c
Dim converterOp As New Func(Of Char, Integer)(Function(input As Char) Char.ConvertToUtf32(input, 0))
Dim result() As Char = {}

For i = converterOp(StartChar) To converterOp(EndChar)
    ReDim Preserve result(UBound(result) + 1)
    result(UBound(result)) = CChar(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i))
Next
```

Given a starting character and an ending character in a range of characters (in this case `"a"c` to `"z"c`), it converts both characters to their Unicode code point values in order to loop numerically from start to end in a `For` loop.  Within each loop iteration, it adds a new array element to the end of the array, converts the current loop index -- which is, again, a Unicode code point somewhere between the start character and the end character -- back to a character, and fills the new array element with that character.

I know you specifically wanted to do it using a `ReDim Preserve`, but this is a more-efficient way to do it since it's not incurring the overhead of re-dimensioning the array in every loop iteration:

```
Const StartChar = "a"c
Const EndChar = "z"c
Dim converterOp As New Func(Of Char, Integer)(Function(input As Char) Char.ConvertToUtf32(input, 0))
Dim intStartCodePoint = converterOp(StartChar)
Dim intEndCodePoint = converterOp(EndChar)
Dim result(intEndCodePoint - intStartCodePoint) As Char
Dim arrIndex = 0

For i = intStartCodePoint To intEndCodePoint
    result(arrIndex) = CChar(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i))
    arrIndex += 1
Next
```

The difference here is that it dimensions the array *before* entering the loop, using the start and end code points to calculate the size of the array.